# Java & Spring Bean: Create a bean with multiple Generic Types

Tags: java, xml, spring, generics, spring-bean

There is a class with 2 Generic Types.

```
public class GenericDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericDao<T, ID> {
...
}
```

I need to initiate it from spring.

```
<bean id="myDao" class="com.xxx.yyy.GenericDao">
    <qualifier type="com.xxx.yyy.Item"/> <!-- Works for T -->
    <!-- Need something for ID -->
    ...
    <property name="name" ref="value"/>
    <property name="name" ref="value"/>
</bean>
```

with **qualifier** tag i can handle **T**. I also need to handle **ID**.

Comment: What properties are you trying to autowire with the qualifier?

Comment: T is a class that i will store it on database. ID is a primary key that can vary for each class. (ID is generally Long)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. `@Qualifier as well as <qualifier>` are for injecting dependencies of beans. But you are not injecting anything into your bean and not injecting your bean anywhere, you are just trying to **define** the bean.

In your case it is important to understand that in xml you are **defining** beans which will be instantiated at **runtime**. And at runtime generic types are erasured: [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

That said it doesn't matter what generic types/hints you can possibly give to Spring it will be completely useless as at runtime - when the spring will instantiate the beans - all generic types information will be lost.

The correct usage of qualifier tag would be if you had:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("main")
  private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;

  // ...
}
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>

  <bean class="example.SimpleMovieCatalog">
      <qualifier value="main"/>
      <!-- inject any dependencies required by this bean -->
  </bean>

  <bean id="movieRecommender" class="example.MovieRecommender"/>

</beans>
```

For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value. 
You can read more [at the spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)